# how to save an image from a picturebox vb

Tags: vb.net, button, picturebox, savefiledialog

I am interested in vb and am confused how to save the contents of a Picturebox as a png file when button1 is clicked. When I try to do it now, it produces the error I show below. I can't figure out how to fix this because I'm new to using visual basic. The debugger seemed to catch something but I can't make sense of it. I would be extremely pleased if someone would help me to fix this. Here is the code:

```html
'*** Acknowlegements  ***
'Ideas for this code came from the MicroSoft "Scribble" sample code, 
'Christian Graus's excellent arcticle on a C++ code called "Doodle" 
'and the MicroSoft website.
'By John Buettner
'26 July 2003
Imports System
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Windows.Forms


Public Class Form
    'Namespace myPaint

    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form  ' Of course ;)

    Dim mousePath As New System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath() 'declare a new Graphic path to follow the mouse movement

    '*** below I declare some values for an Alpha  and other user selected variables
    'these will be used as I expand this program for a higher level use.

    Dim myAlpha As Integer = 100 ' declare a Alpha variable
    Dim myUserColor As New Color() 'this is a color the user selects
    Friend WithEvents Button1 As Button
    Friend WithEvents SaveFileDialog1 As SaveFileDialog
    Dim myPenWidth As Single = 5 'set pen width variable

    '**************************************************************



#Region " Windows Form Designer generated code "

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()

        'This call is required by the Windows Form Designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        'Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call

    End Sub

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    Protected Overloads Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If disposing Then
            If Not (components Is Nothing) Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        End If
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer
    Friend WithEvents PictureBox1 As System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Dim resources As System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager = New System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(GetType(Form))
        Me.PictureBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox()
        Me.Button1 = New System.Windows.Forms.Button()
        Me.SaveFileDialog1 = New System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog()
        CType(Me.PictureBox1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
        Me.SuspendLayout()
        '
        'PictureBox1
        '
        Me.PictureBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.GhostWhite
        Me.PictureBox1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        Me.PictureBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 33)
        Me.PictureBox1.Name = "PictureBox1"
        Me.PictureBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(696, 423)
        Me.PictureBox1.TabIndex = 2
        Me.PictureBox1.TabStop = False
        '
        'Button1
        '
        Me.Button1.Image = Global.Ubernote.My.Resources.Resources.fl
        Me.Button1.ImageAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
        Me.Button1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(12, 4)
        Me.Button1.Name = "Button1"
        Me.Button1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(75, 23)
        Me.Button1.TabIndex = 3
        Me.Button1.Text = "Save"
        Me.Button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = True
        '
        'SaveFileDialog1
        '
        '
        'Form
        '
        Me.AutoScaleBaseSize = New System.Drawing.Size(5, 13)
        Me.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(696, 456)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.Button1)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.PictureBox1)
        Me.Icon = CType(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon"), System.Drawing.Icon)
        Me.Name = "Form"
        Me.Text = "Draw"
        CType(Me.PictureBox1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
        Me.ResumeLayout(False)

    End Sub

#End Region



    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown

        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then ' draw a filled circle if left mouse is down  

            mousePath.StartFigure()    ' The L mouse is down so we need to start a new line in mousePath

        End If

    End Sub


    Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove

        If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then ' draw a filled circle if left mouse is down  

            Try
                mousePath.AddLine(e.X, e.Y, e.X, e.Y)    'Add mouse coordiantes to mousePath

            Catch
                MsgBox("No way, Hose!")
            End Try

        End If

        PictureBox1.Invalidate() 'Repaint the PictureBox using the PictureBox1 Paint event

    End Sub



    Private Sub PictureBox1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Paint
        ' Here is where we do the actual painting

        Try ' error trapping

            myUserColor = (System.Drawing.Color.Black) 'You can remove this line and add a user selected color to
            'change the value of myUserColor

            myAlpha = 100  ' This will give the color a Alpha effect, you can set this to 255 if you want a full color


            Dim CurrentPen = New Pen(Color.FromArgb(myAlpha, myUserColor), myPenWidth) 'Set up the pen

            e.Graphics.DrawPath(CurrentPen, mousePath)  'draw the path! :)

        Catch
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub SaveFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles SaveFileDialog1.FileOk
        Try
            '       Dim FileToSaveAs As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp, SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
            '      PictureBox1.Image.Save(FileToSaveAs, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            'PictureBox1.Image.Save(FileToSaveAs)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MenuItem3.Click
    Dim path As String
    Dim pic As Image
    pic = PictureBox1.Image
    SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    pic.Save(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)
End Sub
```

try this

Comment: Some explanation would turn this into a better answer.

Comment: it gives me an error: NullRefrenceException was unhandled for this:\

Comment: It gives me an error: NullRefrenceException was unhandled for this    pic.Save(SaveFileDialog1.FileName)

Comment: It never shows the file extension that is the main error with this project

Comment: Me.SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "PNG(*.png)|*.png" add this to the dialog filter